# Hide page name in url using htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

here is my url

```html
www.mydomain.com/index.php/Lg-G-Pro-Lite-D686
```

In this url i want to hide index.php using htaccess. So result should be

```html
www.mydomain.com/Lg-G-Pro-Lite-D686
```

Here is my .htaccess file what i tried so far

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After this i am getting 404 not found . Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```